# Define a command on xelatex command line

Tags: xetex

I would like to define the command `\qonly` on the `xelatex` command line to be the string `chapter07`. Later in my LaTeX file I will have an `ifdef` that will provide the argument to an `\includeonly` if `\qonly` is defined.

This works if I am using `latexmk`:

```
$ latexmk -usepretex='\def\qonly{chapter07}' -pdfxe book.tex -bibtex
```

But this does not work with xelatex:

```
$ xelatex '\relax\def\qonly{chapter07}' book.tex
```

It gives me this error:

```
xelatex '\def\qonly{chapter07}' book.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

<*> \def\qonly{chapter07} b
                           ook.tex
? ^D
! Emergency stop.
 ...

<*> \def\qonly{chapter07} b
                           ook.tex
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
$
```

Is there any way do this?

**EDIT:** One of the posters was confused why I have the backquotes above. The reason is that I'm using MacOS and my shell is `zsh`, which interprets the backquotes as a quote mark, so it's necessary to quote it. Here's what happens if I don't provide the backquote:

```
% xelatex \def\qonly{chapter07} book.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `defqonly{chapter07}'.
<*> defqonly{chapter07}
                        book.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Comment: you need to use `\input{book}` on the command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - brilliant. Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Why should I add another answer? Werner says the same, accept this.

Comment: Because I missed that the key difference was `book.tex` vs. `\input{book}`. See my comments to @werner's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass quoted commands to the compiler. Think of whatever follows a call to the compiler as code that should be within a regular TeX file (except if you're passing the tex file itself, as in `xelatex book.tex`). So, drop the use of the quotes and `\input` your source:

```bash
xelatex \def\qonly{chapter07} \input{book}
```

Since `book.tex` is at the end of the input stream, TeX just wants to set it as the character string `book.tex`, not reading in the file `book.tex`, hence the use of `\input{book}`.

Comment: The quotes are for `bash`. Without them, bash treats the \ as an escape character....

Comment: @vy32: Sure. It was not apparent from your post.

Comment: I clarified it. It was actually in a Makefile, but it runs the commands through bash...

Comment: my problem was that I had `book.tex` on the command line rather than `\input{book}`. Apparently it you provide the filename, it is automatically input, but if you provide TeX commands, you need to do the `\input` yourself.